Handling tables in quill
I'm trying to use tables with the Quill WYSIWYG editor. I'm trying to do it in the sandbox: https://quilljs.com/playground/snow . I've added ['table'] to the toolbar, so now it looks like this:
const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block'],
      ['table']
    ],
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow', // or 'bubble'
});

The table icon appeared, however I have no freakin' idea on how to add columns and rows to it. Does anyone know?

Sorry but Quill v2.0.2 doesn't really support table rendering and inserting/editing.
For basic usage, I recommend using the module: https://github.com/soccerloway/quill-better-table
npm install quill-better-table


import QuillBetterTable from 'quill-better-table'

Quill.register({
  'modules/better-table': QuillBetterTable
}, true)

const quill = new Quill('#editor-wrapper', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    table: false,  // disable table module
    'better-table': {
      operationMenu: {
        items: {
          unmergeCells: {
            text: 'Another unmerge cells name'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    keyboard: {
      bindings: QuillBetterTable.keyboardBindings
    }
})

...

  document.body.querySelector('#insert-table')
    .onclick = () => {
      let tableModule = quill.getModule('better-table')
      tableModule.insertTable(3, 3)
    }


If you're feeling adventurous, you could also check this cool project, where they re-write Quill in order to handle table.
Cheers,

Maybe you can try quill table better. This supports toolbar configuration table insertion button(insert table show).
npm i quill-table-better


import QuillTableBetter from 'quill-table-better';
import 'quill-table-better/dist/quill-table-better.css'

Quill.register({
  'modules/table-better': QuillTableBetter
}, true);

const toolbarOptions = [
  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
  ['table-better']
];

const options = {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions,
    table: false,
    'table-better': {
      language: 'en_US',
      menus: ['column', 'row', 'merge', 'table', 'cell', 'wrap', 'delete'],
      toolbarTable: true
    },
    keyboard: {
      bindings: QuillTableBetter.keyboardBindings
    }
  }
};

const quill = new Quill('#editor', options);

